# How to leverage request-promise to request OAuth2 token from Oauth server and include the token in request headers

Tags: javascript, node.js

Disclaimer: I'm very new Node developer and pretty new to javascript also. I have a lot of experience with Java, C++, and frameworks around those, so I understand development paradigms, but I'm not that familiar with how JS is structured or design patterns yet. And I'm in a bit of a pickle to get this done quickly :/

Our node application needs to make requests to services that require OAuth2 authentication.

Our app can successfully request and receive an OAuth bearer token, and it also can make requests to services using that token. But its all very decoupled.

What I'd like to do is hook up an intercepter to the request module (we are using request-promise) that is called as such:

1. The request module passes control to us prior to calling the requested
   service
2. We get our cached copy of the oauth token headers OR request a new token and build the headers (and cache it)
3. We insert the new oauth token headers to the request
4. Then return control to the request module for normal execution

I looked at request-promise and see that it's doing something similar in terms of hooking onto the 'request' module. And looking at the nodejs 'request' module, it looks like there's possibly a hook for adding OAuth headers.

My question is how to I leverage the hook if it exists. And is this the best approach? Finally, is there an example/pattern for this specific case. I see lots of examples for OAuth in node, but most of it is for authenticating an incoming client, not an outgoing request, and the examples I find have a very decoupled process similar to what we already have.

Many thanks in advance for any assistance on this.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't found any documentation about this in the request-promise module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise).

So my guess is that you should have a service RequestBuilder building the options object to pass and that add automatically all what you need. So you'll request will end up looking like this :

```
rp(RequestBuilder.get('uri'))
```

With RequestBuilder.get building a get function and adding necessary headers.